# How to access to variable of parent scope in c++?

Tags: c++, scope

Let's imagine I have piece of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int a = 5;
    {
        int a = 12;
        std::cout << a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to cout `a==5` from outside scope, but `main::a` doesn't work surely. Is there any workaround?

Comment: It is impossible.

Comment: Not possible to do. C++ is not JavaScript.

Comment: The workaround is to rename `a` in the inner scope or `a` in the outer scope :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A (let's say) workaround:

```
int main()
{

    int a = 5;
    int *pa = &a;
    {
        int a = 12;
        std::cout << (*pa);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively,

```
int main()
{

    int a = 5;
    int& ra = a;
    {
        int a = 12;
        std::cout << ra;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or simpler `int& aref = a;` and use `aref` inside. But imo one should just change the name of the variable if both are to be used.

Comment: Yes of course - but changing the name of the variable is cheating even more :-)

Comment: While this will "work", it is also a *horrible* practice.  If you are using the scope operator like this, the variables inside the scope should not mask variables outside the scope - especially if you want to use those variables.  Additionally, the reference method would be far preferable to pointers here.

Comment: @ZacHowland The OP has not explained the *why* of the question. Let's hope it's not for any practical usage :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, it's similar to ilya answer but without polluting the parent scope

```
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  {
    int& outer_a = a;
    int a = 2;
    std::cout << outer_a;
  }
}
```